# Задача на изменение строк Java

Tags: java, строки

По заданию необходимо решить следующую задачу: Дана строка, состоящая из русских слов, набранных заглавными буквами и разделенных пробелами (одним или несколькими). Преобразовать каждое слово в строке, заменив в нем все предыдущие вхождения его последней буквы на символ «.» (точка). Например, слово «МИНИМУМ» надо преобразовать в «.ИНИ.УМ». Количество пробелов между словами не изменять.
Написал следующий код, чтобы двигаться по строке:

```
 String str ="МИНИМУМ";
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(str.length() - 1)){

            }
        }
```

Но не могу сделать замену. Очень нужна помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: И не сможешь. В яве строки неизменяемые. Нужно собирать новую.

Comment: Было бы хорошо узнать как это сделать. Не подскажете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
package test;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "МИНИМУМ  МАСИМУМ И ПРОЧЕЕ";

    String result =
        Stream.of(str.split(" ")).map(Main::replaceWord).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

    System.out.println(result);
  }

  static String replaceWord(String input) {
    if (input.length() > 0) {
      return input.replace(input.charAt(input.length() - 1), '.').substring(0, input.length() - 1)
          + input.charAt(input.length() - 1);
    } else {
      return input;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Можно еще вопрос задать по  двум задачам, но в них я почти ничего не понимаю. Задачи про работу с файлами, Добавил работу с файлами, но как что-то заменять или добавлять - не очень понятно.

Comment: Задавайте также вопросы предвариетльно оформляя и попытки решения

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас создам и все добавлю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242751/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-txt-%d0%b2-java

Comment: @QypeR реализовал через stream api

Comment: @Aziz Umarov, извините, но, кажется, в Вашем коде небольшая неточность: ошибка `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`, если пробелов между словами больше 1.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов а так лучше?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, да, поставил + :)

Answer (score 0):

Просто ещё один вариант в копилку

```
    String sentence = "МИНИМУМ МАКСИМУМ МОЛОКО";
    StringBuilder newSentence = new StringBuilder(sentence);

    int index = sentence.length()-1;

    while (index >= 0)
    {
        while (index >=0 && sentence.charAt(index) == ' ') index--;
        int wordEndIndex = index;
        index--;
        while (index >=0 && sentence.charAt(index) != ' ') {
            if (sentence.charAt(index) == sentence.charAt(wordEndIndex)) newSentence.setCharAt(index, '.');
            index--;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(newSentence.toString());
```